# Replacing greyscale pixel values with colors from sample PNG image

Tags: python

I am trying to apply colors from a gradient image to a grayscale (in RGB format i.e. R=G=B) one. For now the code looks at the R channel and uses that value to copy a color from a certain band of a 255 px tall gradient via the R channel value acting as the Y coordinate. As an example, a pixel in image 1 at (0,0) has a value of (0,0.0), the code should replace it with the color (53,18,106) from (10,0) in the second image (x is arbitrary here, my sample gradient is 100x255). Here's my code:

```
import os, numpy, PIL
from PIL import Image

# Access all PNG files in directory
allfiles=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
imlistmaster=[filename for filename in allfiles if  filename[-4:] in [".png",".PNG"]]
imlistGradient=[filename for filename  in imlistmaster if "grad" in filename]
imlistSample=[filename for filename in imlistmaster if "Sample" in filename]

# Get dimensions of images
w1,h1=Image.open(imlistSample[0]).size
N1=len(imlistSample)
w2,h2=Image.open(imlistGradient[0]).size
N2=len(imlistGradient)

#Create array based on gradient
for im in imlistGradient:
    imarr2=numpy.array(Image.open(im),dtype=numpy.uint8)
    pix2=Image.open(im).load()

# Convert grayscale to RGB values based on gradient
for im in imlistSample:
    filename1 = os.path.basename(imlistSample[0])
    pix1=Image.open(im).load()
    for x in range(w1):
        for y in range (h1):
            color=pix1[x, y]
            color=list(color)
            colorvalue=color[0]
            newcolor=pix2[10,colorvalue]
            pix1=newcolor
```

image: [image]

gradient: [image]

(imgur because I can't embed yet)

When I run the code, `color=pix1[x, y]` throws "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple". Which is odd, as both x and y show up as integers in variable explorer and shouldn't Image.load explicitly takes 2 coordinates in the form of (x,y)? Also while looking around in the variable explorer it does look like at least one iteration worked as `newcolor` has the expected value of (53,18,106) from the gradient. Frankly I'm stumped

Comment: `color=pix1[x, y]` will not retrieve a value for a given pixel at coordinate x,y. You'll need to use `pix1.getpixel((x,y))` instead.

Comment: @ Stephen Replacing that line now gives "AttributeError: 'PixelAccess' object has no attribute 'getpixel'" For reference, here is the new code: `(r,g,b)=pix1.getpixel((x,y)) newcolor=pix2[10,r] pix1=newcolor` Could you provide a sample implementation? apologies I'm quite new at this.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I'm in the wrong here. When you use `.load()` it returns a `PixelAccess` object which does support the `pix1[x,y]` syntax that you were using. The logic in the loop seems to be the issue though, but I don't know enough about how it should work to give you an answer.

Comment: @Stephen I'm trying to iterate through each pixel in the original image, get the R channel value for that pixel, and then replace the RGB value with those from the corresponding spot (10,R) on the gradient

Answer (score 0):

The culprit ended up being `pix1=newcolor`, changing to `pix1[x,y]=newcolor` solved the tuple problem. Odd that the error would identify the wrong line but oh well. This also explains the partial success, the value was being found and copied correctly and failing when being overwritten.